# log4j2 lookup default value with empty contextPath

Tags: log4j2

Trying to create a log4j2 configuration using the ${web:contextPath} lookup worked fine, until I tried to use that with an empty contextPath.

Is there a way to specify a default value if the lookup returns an empty string?

If the contextPath is empty, I would like to specify a default value somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a fallback value within the configuration like so:

```
${web:contextPath:-default-value}
```

("default-value" being the fallback value). Note the hyphen in front of the fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define it as a property in the config.

For an xml config

```
<Properties>
   <Property name="contextPath">default value</Property>
</Properties>
```

Assuming that the web lookup process works the same as a system property lookup then it should fall back to the value defined in the properties section if the web lookup fails.

Comment: Looking in `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.lookup(LogEvent event, String var)`, the problem is that the fallback is called only if the value is null, but in this case it's just an empty string.

Comment: It seems that the web lookup returns ctx.getContextPath(), so it is entirely dependent on how the ServletContext initializes the context path. In the MockServletContext constructor of their source `this.contextPath = ""` I would assume the context you have does something similiar.

Comment: Yes, for an application deployed as root for a host, the contextPath will be "".
Seems I'm out of luck.

Comment: Not exactly, you should be able to create your own property lookup plugin. Simply extend the WebLookup and override the lookup method to return null if the retrieved contextPath is "". Then the usual default method should work. Or simply return the default value you would like from the lookup.

Comment: Some limited doc on the subject https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html#Lookups